# R: Creating a random number in function call

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following function,

```
foo <- function(x) {
  lapply(seq(sample(1:5,1)), function(y) x)
}
```

And suppose I do this,

```
foo(runif(1))
```

I get the following result,

```
[[1]]
[1] 0.5354641
[[2]]
[1] 0.5354641
```

Or some other random number. What I want is for there to be two different numbers as the output. Is this possible? In other words I would like,

```
[[1]]
[1] 0.5354641
[[2]]
[1] 0.2895715
```

So I'm wondering can I write a function like

```
bar <- function(x) {
    rand <- function() {
        runif(x)
    }
}
```

And call it like `foo(bar(1))` to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this almost works,

```
bar <- function(x) {
    rand <- function() {
        runif(x)
    }
}
```

and the following,

```
foo <- function(x) {
  lapply(seq(sample(1:5,1)), function(y) x)
}
```

and calling `foo(bar(1))`.